# Why dont online email services get blacklisted?

Tags: email, service, web, cloud

Why don't online email services such as mailChimp get blacklisted due to the huge amount of emails they send?

Thanks!

Comment: Why should a large volume of email result in being blacklisted?

Comment: Sending out an email to a huge list of users are harmful if your domain is new or you don't follow email practices including domain.

so it becomes necessary to check domain reputation first by using http://multirbl.valli.org/ or https://tools.pepipost.com or few more

Once you are confident that your domain is not listed in DNSBLs then check for email body(text-to-image ratio (it should be 65%-35%)) which also includes verifying SPF and DKIM with ISPs (inbox providers).

ESPs helps you with all the above norms to build your reputation due to which they know how to save their own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They go to a lot of effort to protect their IP's. They limit new users, and the size of their subscriber lists until they are proven trustworthy to limit the damage caused by people abusing their system. They also ask where you obtained the list in case of uploading an existing one (which can’t really be policed, but will get your account suspended if they find out otherwise). The large number of emails they send collectively also plays a part, as this keeps the percentage of emails marked spam down.

An important part is also the CAN-SPAM act, which has two obvious rules for each email:

1. Must include an unsubscribe link
2. Must include a physical senders address

All legitimate business emails conform to this, and the ESP’s enforce it in their emails. If you try and send an email through their system without either of those things, they either add it dynamically based on your account details, or simply won’t let you send the email. Also, any spam complaints about emails that conform to the CAN-SPAM act (and are not obvious spam, rather sent in good faith) are easier to defend and appeal/reverse if blacklisting does occur...

Comment: Thank you for you're explaination